# What is the proper way to instantiate multiple objects from a script while in the editor in Unity?

Tags: unity

I would like to, for example, be able to spawn a wall of stacked boxes and be able to play with the number of boxes in each dimension in the editor (previously I would be instantiating these at runtime, but it is annoying to not be able to see these in the editor).

[image]

Currently I am using a bit of a work around, I am using the OnValidate method to achieve this, but its a bit of a bodge and my instantiated items do not spawn in play mode, I get the following error on play:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Lattice' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
Lattice.<OnValidate>b__8_0 () (at Assets/Lattice.cs:22)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallDelayFunctions () (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:346)
```

Here is the script I am currently using:

```
public class Lattice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int nX=1, nY=1, nZ=1;
    public float offsetX=1, offsetY=1, offsetZ=1;
    public GameObject item;

    // Validate called only in editor and only on variable change
    void OnValidate()
    {
        Clean(); // remove old items
        UnityEditor.EditorApplication.delayCall+=()=>
        {
            spawnBox3Grid(item, transform, nX, nY, nZ, offsetX, offsetY, offsetZ);
        };
    }

    void Clean()
    {
        foreach(Transform childT in transform)
        {
            UnityEditor.EditorApplication.delayCall+=()=>
            {
                //Debug.Log(childT.gameObject.name);
                DestroyImmediate(childT.gameObject);
            };
        }
    }

    void spawnBox2Grid(GameObject obj, Transform parent, Vector3 startingPos, int nItemsY, int nItemsZ, float zOff=1.0f, float yOff=1.0f, int k=0)
    {
        
        Vector3 boxPos = startingPos + new Vector3(0, yOff/2,-zOff*nItemsZ/2);
        Vector3 zOffset = new Vector3(  0, 0, zOff);
        Vector3 yOffset = new Vector3(  0, yOff, 0);

        for (int j=0; j<nItemsY; j++)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<nItemsZ; i++)
            {
                GameObject instance = Instantiate(obj, boxPos, Quaternion.identity, parent);
                instance.name = string.Format( "obj_{0}_{1}_{2}", i, j, k);
                instance.transform.localPosition = boxPos;
                instance.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;

                boxPos+=zOffset;
            }
            boxPos-=nItemsZ*zOffset;
            boxPos+=yOffset;
        }

    }

    void spawnBox3Grid(GameObject obj, Transform parent, int nItemsX, int nItemsY, int nItemsZ, float xOff=1.0f, float yOff=1.0f, float zOff=1.0f)
    {
        
        Vector3 xOffset = new Vector3(  xOff,0, 0);
        Vector3 boxPos = new Vector3(-xOff*nItemsX/2,0,0);
        for (int k=0; k<nItemsX; k++)
        {
            spawnBox2Grid(obj, parent, boxPos,nItemsY,nItemsZ, yOff, zOff, k);
            boxPos += xOffset;
        }
        
    }

}
```

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LyV7cEQyZMk) is probably closer to what I want, but I don't entirely understand it and was hoping there was a simpler way.

**Edit:**

Some extra context:
Delaying the `DestroyImmediately` calls seems to be the only way to delete objects from inside `OnValidate` and if I don't delay the `Instantiate` calls I get `SendMessage cannot be called during Awake, CheckConsistency, or OnValidate`.

**Edit 2:**

I guess I can use this code for previewing in the editor then use a scriptable object to store the parameters of my Lattice objects and then re-instantiate things at runtime? But that error that I'm getting; is it trying to run `OnValidate` just before play? (When presumably, the things I've instantiated aren't stored permanently so the lattice object is lost?) There has got to be a cleaner way of doing this...